# How to match font with full block

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

trying to make background color for text on canvas I am trying to use full block but it seems that block is always bigger then the text.

Which setting should make this work?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7MHC3PHLBEE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="240   "
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script>

function test(str){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);


  var bg="";
  for(i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++){
    bg+= "\u2588";
  }

  ctx.font = "25px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFAA00";
  ctx.fillText(bg, 10, 150);


  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillText(str, 10, 150)

}

test("abcdefg");


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write text on canvas with background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900117/write-text-on-canvas-with-background)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with **monospace** :

```
  ctx.font = "30px monospace";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFAA00";
  ctx.fillText(bg, 10, 150);

  ctx.font = "30px monospace";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillText(str, 10, 150)
```

It solved problem for my case at least!