# Add background to text in Pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, text, graphics, pixi.js

Is there any way I can add a background to my text in Pixi.js? I'm looking for an effect like this:

[image: Highlighted text example.]

Creating a background sprite, and giving it the same position and dimensions as the text object does not work here, as that would always give me a rectangle which is not what I want. I guess I could make on text object per line and use that approach, but since the text is arbitrarily set by the user I would have to work out my own linebreaking algorithm to be able to do that. That seems overly complicated.

Here is my code without any background ([fiddle](https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/Pgvm4aZi8DYOmfGZpll0c)):

```
var app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x2c3e50
});

document.body.appendChild(app.view);

var text = new PIXI.Text("HELLO\nWORLD!", {
    align: "center"
})

text.anchor.set(0.5);
text.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
text.y = app.renderer.height / 2;

app.stage.addChild(text);
```

Comment: Ive only just started looking at Pixi so I dont know alot, but it looks like measureText will split the lines for you and give you the width for each line and their height.  You could then draw them maybe? `PIXI.TextMetrics.measureText("HELLO\nWORLD!",text.style)`

Comment: @PAEz Thanks! That looks very, very promising. I will take a closer look at it later.

Comment: Seems its not a pixi problem so much as thats just how it is with canvas.  This SO will explain....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900117/write-text-on-canvas-with-background